# How to generate link_to equivalent with js including csrf protection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to send a patch request to path:

```
generate PATCH  /tournaments/:id/generate/:groups/:finals_no/:prefinals/:two_g/:three_g/:four_g(.:format) tournaments#generate
```

The twist is, the parameters after `generate` are taken from jquery function.

I managed to get something that can send a `PATCH` request:

```
function generate_groups(){
  var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
  read_values();
  x.open("PATCH",root+"/generate/"+(four_team_groups+three_team_groups+two_team_groups)+"/"+finals_fights+"/"+pre_finals_fights+"/"+two_team_groups+"/"+three_team_groups+"/"+four_team_groups);
  x.send(null);
}
```

And try to trigger it from

```
<button function="generate_groups" id="gg" data-remote="true">Generate!</button>
```

The problem is CSRF protection kicks in and I get 422 error from server.

I know that this is something that probably can be dealt with with UJS, but I failed to find out how.

I aim to get something that can be clicked and the proper url will get patched to server. It doesn't have to be button.

I'm using Rails 4.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used data-method instead of data-remote and it did the trick.